# how to use json back slash In Android(Java)

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

I'm new to Android.

I want to convert below Swift code to Android(Java).
I tryed putting two backSlash in Java but code has error.

How can I convert Swift to Java below code?
Please help me.

In Swift

```
let body = "{\"to\":\"\(token)\",\"notification\":{\"body\":\"\(message)\",\"badge\":\"1\"}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `\()` in Java. To convert your `Swift String` to `Java String`, use like below:

```
String jsonString = "{\"to\": " + token + ", \"notification\": { \"body\": " +  message + ", \"badge\": \"1\"}}";
```

Here `message` and `token` are variables.